# Increase buffer size or time for video-js HTML5 player

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

how do I increase buffer on video-js HTML5 player? I have a US server and in the US is all fine but clients in EU have loading issues related to video caching.
buffer size in video.js is constant value and I want to change it.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can now customize the buffer length by modifying `videojs.Hls.GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH` for change buffer size of HLS videos, I tryed and It's work for me

Comment: @Steve Harrig please mark as answer if it work for you

Comment: How can I use it? videojs.Hls is deprecated and using videojs.tech().Hls does not have GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH property

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

For me this has worked (video.js 7.7.6):

```
let player = videojs('my-player');

player.vhs.options_.externHls.GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH = 60;
```

You might also need to change the MAX_GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH value, e.g.:

```
player.vhs.options_.externHls.MAX_GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH = 80;
```

The case when you might need to increase buffer length values is when your viewers are facing buffering during playback (e.g. the spinner instead of a video). Video.js may give a warnings in the console that means its buffer values have been changed.

Be careful with a buffer length values. If it is a live streaming the browser will continue to load (buffer) video segments and the higher buffer values are the more MB will be downloaded even after pausing/stopping the player.

Video.js DOCS: https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming

Video.js Troubleshooting:
https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

Used Type Definitions for VideoJS:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/video.js

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (video.js 8.0.4):

```
videojs.Vhs.GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH = 60*30;
videojs.Vhs.MAX_GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH = 60*60;
let player = videojs('my-player');
```

Ref https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/7473